# History of Braids

Tags: reference-request, topology

I am looking for papers or books that describe the history of the development of braid theory, mainly during the 19th and the 20th century. I know Moritz Epple book on the history of the theory of knots ("Die Entstehung der Knotentheorie"), which gives already several surveys on Gauss, Hurwitz and Artin's works on braids, but I was wondering if there are other manuscripts which are dedicated only to the history of braids.

Thank you!